# Can an OP delete their own locked post?

Tags: discussion, locked-posts

The question [How to solve this error? --> Conversion from type 'Byte()' to type 'String' is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63985275/how-to-solve-this-error-conversion-from-type-byte-to-type-string-is-n#comment113152152_63985275) has been locked because of self-vandalism, *perhaps* caused by the OP wanting to obliterate their post because they were not aware that they could delete it when it all went wrong.

[A comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63985275/how-to-solve-this-error-conversion-from-type-byte-to-type-string-is-n#comment113182521_63985275) on that post suggests:

> If you want to delete your question, please just do so by pressing the "delete" button underneath the tags on this question. There's nothing preventing you from doing that, rather than vandalising is.

But both [What is a locked post?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) (MSE) and [What is a “locked” post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) (MSO) do not state that the OP can delete a locked post, so there is missing information.

**Can an OP delete their own question which has been locked?**

It would leave an avenue for a graceful, or at least discreet, withdrawal.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221900/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-morton-can-an-op-delete-their-own-locked-post).

Comment: A locked post is like in a frozen state, nothing good or bad can happen to it while being locked. Not being able to delete it without consent of the moderators makes sense then. However, the post linked here is now unlocked and could be deleted right away. The withdrawal avenue is open again.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I haven't seen the locked message just now because the many duplicates box was too prominent. Maybe the locked message banner should be placed on top.

Comment: Also interesting. The listed five duplicates are not duplicates of themselves, only one is a duplicate but of another question. Asking a question that is solved by five other question that aren't solved by each other probably doesn't happen.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, the original poster does not have any special privileges when it comes to locked posts. That means that, in this case as in any other, the asker does not have the ability to delete their own question because it is currently locked by a moderator.

You mention [Adriaan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63985275/how-to-solve-this-error-conversion-from-type-byte-to-type-string-is-n#comment113182521_63985275) advising the asker to delete their own question rather than vandalize it. That's a pretty standard comment for reviewers to leave in cases of vandalism. Note that it was left some 16 hours ago, which was several hours before [the question was locked by a moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63985275/revisions). The advice in the comment made sense at the time it was posted. It doesn't make sense anymore after the question was locked. This is why comments are temporary. :-)

As for the implication that this exception could perhaps be a nice feature, allowing the asker to clean up their own messes, unfortunately, no, it would not be. Moderators need to be able to lock questions to *prevent* their deletion. Adding in this loophole would defeat one important purpose of locking questions.